# jQuery call event on keydown or keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, keydown, keyup

I am trying to change the color of a div element on a keydown and keyup but i just cant seem to get it to work. Ive check every example i can find on the internet but my code will just not seem to work.

All of the examples i find seem to use a form input text field as a target for the keypress. I dont want to do that. here is my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 'A')
    {
        alert('key was pressed');
        $(#k1).css('background-color', "blue");
    }
});
```

My thought is that $(document) is not the correct thing to have there because the function is never called. But because all the examples i find use a textfield input, i just cant figure out what to put there.

Comment: Have you tried with `$("#k1")`

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/onohoj/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 65){
        alert('Pressed key was: '+ e.which );
        $("#k1").css( { backgroundColor:"blue" } );
    }
});
```

If you need `$('input')` instead of `$(document)` feel free to use it, 
`65` is the `event.which` for <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things. Firstly, the `event.which` will return a number which correlates to a key. And secondly, your jquery target needs to be a string. So, change the `=='A'` to `==65` and `$(#k1)` to `$("#k1")` and it will work. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AeBtV/

js

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
 if(e.which == 65)
 {
    alert('A key was pressed');
    $("#k1").css('background-color', "blue");
 }
});
```

Note on key code numbers:

The range is from 65-90 for A to Z. Thus A is 65, Z is 90, and R is 82.

Comment: I noticed that stuff but as i said before, the function is never called in the first place. I'm not even reaching those errors yet even though i already fixed them. The problem has something to do with 'document'

Answer (score 0):

I've trapped keyup and keydown events using .live:

$("#my_id").live('keydown',function(event) {

...

});

Comment: `.live` is deprecated! And why would it help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your `which` condition isn't valid. Should be 65 as others mentioned.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

If you scroll down, you can type in any key and see the which value of each key.

Alternatively, you can do

```
console.log(e.which);
```